# iCal Parser display number of events

Tags: php, xml-parsing, icalendar

I have researched thoroughly and I could not find a solution. I am new to PHP and working through the language to learn as much as I can. I would appreciate any help!

I am using an iCal Parser and trying to limit it so it only returns 15 events at a time. How can I do this?

```
    <?php
    /* iCal Parser - Some PHP functions to parse an iCal calendar into a usable PHP object.
     *               Also convert the object into pretty HTML.
     *
     * Copyright (C) 2006 Adam Wolfe Gordon
     *
     * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
     * modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
     * as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
     * of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
     *
     * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
     * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
     * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
     * GNU General Public License for more details.
     *
     * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
     * along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
     * Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301, USA.
     */

     // Blatantly stolen from http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php
     // Convert xml into a nice object
    class XmlElement {
      var $name;
      var $attributes;
      var $content;
      var $children;
     };

    function xml_to_object($xml) {
    $parser = xml_parser_create();
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);
    xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $xml, $tags);
    xml_parser_free($parser);

    $elements = array();  // the currently filling [child] XmlElement array
    $stack = array();
      foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $index = count($elements);
        if ($tag['type'] == "complete" || $tag['type'] == "open") {
          $elements[$index] = new XmlElement;
          $elements[$index]->name = $tag['tag'];
          $elements[$index]->attributes = $tag['attributes'];
          $elements[$index]->content = $tag['value'];
          if ($tag['type'] == "open") {  // push
        $elements[$index]->children = array();
        $stack[count($stack)] = &$elements;
        $elements = &$elements[$index]->children;
          }
        }
        if ($tag['type'] == "close") {  // pop
      $elements = &$stack[count($stack) - 1];
      unset($stack[count($stack) - 1]);
        }
      }
      return $elements[0];  // the single top-level element
    }

    // Not stolen
    // Fetch text from an iCal URL and convert it into xml   $myfile = file_get_contents($URL);
    function ical2xml($URL) {
      $myfile = file_get_contents($URL);
      $myfile = str_replace("\n ", "", $myfile);
      $myfile = str_replace("&", " and ", $myfile);
      $mylines = split("\n", $myfile);

      $xml = "";    
      foreach($mylines as $line) {
        if($line == "")
          continue;

    list($key,$val) = split(":", $line);
    $key = trim($key, "\r\n");
    $val = trim($val, "\r\n");
    $val = str_replace("\n", "", $val);
    $val = str_replace("\r", "", $val);

    $attribs = split(";", $key);
    $key = $attribs[0];
    $attribs = array_slice($attribs, 1);

    $myattribs = " ";
    foreach($attribs as $attrib) {
      list($att, $attval) = split("=", $attrib);
      $myattribs .= "$att=\"$attval\" ";
    }
    $myattribs = rtrim($myattribs);

    // BEGIN and END keywords
    if($key == 'BEGIN') {
      $xml .= "<$val$myattribs>\n";
    } else if($key == 'END') {
      $xml .= "</$val>\n";
    } else {
      $xml .= "<$key$myattribs>$val</$key>\n";
    }
     }

      return $xml;
    }

    // Event class
    class event {
      var $starttime;
      var $endtime;
      var $allday;
      var $rrulefreq;
      var $rruledays;
      var $rruleuntil;
      var $description;
      var $location;
      var $summary;
    };

    // Calendar class
    class calendar {
      var $name;
      var $timezone;
      var $description;
      var $events = array();
    };

    // Timezone class
    class timezone {
      var $namestd;
      var $namedst;
      var $offsetstd;
      var $offsetdst;
    };

    // Convert a time in iCal's ugly format to a unix timestamp
    function ical_time_to_timestamp($time) {
      $hour = substr($time, 9, 2);
      if($hour == "")
        $hour = 0;
      $min = substr($time, 11, 2);
      if($min == "")
        $min = 0;
      $sec =  substr($time, 13, 2);
      if($sec == "")
        $sec = 0;
      $mon = substr($time, 4, 2);
      $day = substr($time, 6, 2);
      $year = substr($time, 0, 4);
      return mktime($hour, $min, $sec, $mon, $day, $year);
    }

    // The day the world ends (for Unix users)
    $endoftime = ical_time_to_timestamp("20380118T000000");

    // Event comparison function for sorting
    function cmp($a, $b) {
      if(!(is_object($a) && is_object($b)))
    return 0;
  if($a->starttime == $b->starttime)
    return 0;
  return ($a->starttime < $b->starttime) ? -1 : 1;
}

// Convert XML into a calendar object
function xml_to_calendar($xml) {
  $mycal = new calendar;
  $eventcount = 0;

  $thecal = xml_to_object($xml);

  foreach($thecal->children as $child) {
    switch($child->name) {
    case "X-WR-CALNAME":
      $mycal->name = $child->content;
      break;
    case "X-WR-CALDESC":
      $mycal->description = $child->content;
      break;
    case "VTIMEZONE":
      $mycal->timezone = new timezone;
      foreach($child->children as $data) {
    switch($data->name) {
    case "STANDARD":
      foreach($data->children as $sec) {
        switch($sec->name) {
        case "TZNAME":
          $mycal->timezone->namestd = $sec->content;
          break;
        case "TZOFFSETTO":
          $mycal->timezone->offsetstd = $sec->content;
          break;
        default:
          break;
        }
      }
      break;
    case "DAYLIGHT":
      foreach($data->children as $sec) {
        switch($sec->name) {
        case "TZNAME":
          $mycal->timezone->namedst = $sec->content;
          break;
        case "TZOFFSETTO":
          $mycal->timezone->offsetdst = $sec->content;
          break;
        default:
          break;
        }
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
      }
      break;
    case "VEVENT":
      $i = $eventcount;
      $mycal->events[$i] = new event;
      $mycal->events[$i]->allday = FALSE;
      $eventcount++;
      foreach($child->children as $data) {
    switch($data->name) {
    case "DTSTART":
      if(substr($data->content, 9, 6) == "") {
        $mycal->events[$i]->allday = TRUE;
        $mycal->events[$i]->starttime = ical_time_to_timestamp($data->content . "T000000");
      } else
        $mycal->events[$i]->starttime = ical_time_to_timestamp($data->content);
      break;
    case "DTEND":
      if(substr($data->content, 9, 6) == "") {
        $mycal->events[$i]->allday = TRUE;
        $mycal->events[$i]->endtime = ical_time_to_timestamp($data->content . "T000000");
      } else
        $mycal->events[$i]->endtime = ical_time_to_timestamp($data->content);
      break;
    case "DURATION":
      $mycal->events[$i]->endtime = $mycal->events[$i]->starttime + substr($data->content, 2, strlen($data->content) - 1);
      break;
    case "RRULE":
      $myrrule = split(";", $data->content);
      // Unless otherwise specified, repeating events go until the end of time
      $mycal->events[$i]->rruleuntil = $endoftime;
      foreach($myrrule as $part) {
        list($a, $b) = split("=", $part);
        switch($a) {
        case "FREQ":
          $mycal->events[$i]->rrulefreq = $b;
          break;
        case "BYDAY":
          $mycal->events[$i]->rruledays = $b;
          break;
        case "UNTIL":
          $mycal->events[$i]->rruleuntil = ical_time_to_timestamp($b);
          break;
        default:
          break;
        }
      }
      break;
    case "DESCRIPTION":
      $mycal->events[$i]->description = $data->content;
      break;
    case "LOCATION":
      $mycal->events[$i]->location = $data->content;
      break;
    case "SUMMARY":
      $mycal->events[$i]->summary = $data->content;
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
  }

  // Sort events by start date/time
  usort($mycal->events, "cmp");

  return $mycal;
}

// Take in an iCal object and spit out pretty HTML.
function objToHTML($thecal) {
  // Days of the week
  $shortdays = array(   "MO"=>"Mon",
            "TU"=>"Tue",
            "WE"=>"Wed",
            "TH"=>"Thu",
            "FR"=>"Fri",
            "SA"=>"Sat",
            "SU"=>"Sun"
            );

  // Global variables from the config file
  global $timeformat;
  global $dateformat;
  global $noyearformat;
  global $nodayformat;
  global $xthday;

  $nc = "<table>";
foreach($thecal->events as $event) {

if($event->starttime > time() || ($event->rrulefreq && (time() < $event->rruleuntil || $event->rruleuntil == $endoftime))) {

      if($event->rrulefreq == "WEEKLY") {
    $days = str_replace(",", ", ", $event->rruledays);
    $repdays = split(",", $event->rruledays);
    foreach($repdays as $repday) {
      $days = str_replace($repday, $shortdays[$repday], $days);
    }

    $prefix = "Every week on $shortdays";

    if($event->starttime > time()) {
      if($event->allday == FALSE) {
        $fromto = " starting " . date($dateformat, $event->starttime) . " from " . date($timeformat, $event->starttime) . " to " . date($timeformat, $event->endtime);
      } else {
        $fromto = " all day starting " . date($dateformat, $event->starttime);
      }
    } else {
      if($event->allday == FALSE) {
        $fromto = " from " . date($timeformat, $event->starttime) . " to " . date($timeformat, $event->endtime);
      } else {
        $fromto = ", all day";
      }
    }

    if($event->rruleuntil != $endoftime) {
      $until = " until " . date($dateformat, $event->rruleuntil);
    } else {
      $until = "";
    }
      } else if($event->rrulefreq == "MONTHLY") {
    $prefix = "The " . date($xthday, $event->starttime) . " day of each month";

    if($event->starttime > time()) {
      if($event->allday == FALSE) {
        $fromto = " starting " . date($nodayformat, $event->starttime) . " from " . date($timeformat, $event->starttime) . " to " . date($timeformat, $event->endtime);
      } else {
        $fromto = " starting " . date($nodayformat, $event->starttime);
      }
    } else {
      if($event->allday == FALSE) {
        $fromto = " from " . date($timeformat, $event->starttime) . " to " . date($timeformat, $event->endtime);
      } else {
        $fromto = ", all day";
      }
    }

    if($event->rruleuntil != $endoftime) {
      $until = " until " . date($nodayformat, $event->rruleuntil);
    } else {
      $until = "";
    }
      } else if($event->rrulefreq == "DAILY") {
    $prefix = "Every day";

    if($event->starttime > time()) {
      if($event->allday == FALSE) {
        $fromto = " starting " . date($dateformat, $event->starttime) . " from " . date($timeformat, $event->starttime) . " to " . date($timeformat, $event->endtime);
      } else {
        $fromto = " all day starting " . date($dateformat, $event->starttime);
      }
    } else {
      if($event->allday == FALSE) {
        $fromto = " from " . date($timeformat, $event->starttime) . " to " . date($timeformat, $event->endtime);
      } else {
        $fromto = " all day";
      }
    }


    if($event->rruleuntil != $endoftime) {
      $until = " until " . date($dateformat, $event->rruleuntil);
    } else {
      $until = "";
    }
      } else if($event->rrulefreq == "YEARLY") {
    $prefix = date($noyearformat, $event->starttime);

    if($event->allday == FALSE) {
      $fromto = " from " . date($timeformat, $event->starttime) . " to " . date($timeformat, $event->endtime);
    } else {
      $fromto = ", all day";
    }

    if($event->rruleuntil != $endoftime) {
      $until = " until " . date("Y", $event->rruleuntil);
    } else {
      $until = "";
    }
      } else {
    $prefix = date($dateformat, $event->starttime);

    $until = "";
      }


      $nc .= "<tr><td><font size='1' face='Verdana'>" . $prefix . $fromto . $until . "</font></td>\n";


      $nc .= "<td><font size='1' face='Verdana'>" . $event->summary . "</font></td></tr>\n";
    }
  }
  $nc .= "</table>";

  return $nc;
}
function endElement($parser, $event) {
global $prefix, $event, $fromto, $until, $description;
static $counter = 0;
if ($event == "ITEM" && !(++$counter > 15)) {
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You have any advice for me?

Comment: @JakeGould I don't see a solution on the linked post.  If it hasn't been answered there, I guess it's okay to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean 15 events (what starts with BEGIN:VEVENT and ends with END:VEVENT in a icalendar file) or do you mean 15 instances of event (each instance is defined as a date at which the VEVENT happens as per is recurence rule (or just the DTSTART / DTEND in case no RRULE is present).

in case you only want 15 events, you just need to modify function `objToHTML($thecal)`, just after `if($event->starttime > time() || ($event->rrulefreq && (time() < $event->rruleuntil || $event->rruleuntil == $endoftime))) {` to count until you reach 15

in case you want 15 instances, you will need to write an enumerator to replace the `$prefix . $fromto . $until` strings computations with actual instances dates and then count them until you've reached 15.